# div ignores previous div

Tags: css, html, overlay

I'm having an issue with my divs. For some reason unknown to me my main div ignores the nav div and positions on top of it. Can someone assist?

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/lschoebel/6WuSm/

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand img-responsive" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo3.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="company.html">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>




<div id="main-content" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
    <section id="main" role="main">



<article id="post-4471">



        <div id="intro" class="row">
        <div class="post-4471 page type-page status-publish hentry entry">

            <h1>Mobile Consulting Services—Map Your Mobile Strategy</h1>
<p>A few years ago, the mobile space didn’t exist. Today, it is thriving.<br>
Since the inception of mobile, HarborDev has been there. We bring unparalleled mobile strategy expertise to the table, driving engagement programs for leading enterprise and consumer-facing clients.</p>

        </div>
    </div>


    <section class="panel-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="post-4471 page type-page status-publish hentry entry narrow-entry">
                <h3>Consulting as a Service (CaaS)</h3>
<p>CaaS is mobile consulting at its finest. It is flexible, on-demand, and customized. There is no “one-size-fits-all” approach. Your needs are your own, your strategy should be too. Here are a few things we can assist you with:</p>
<ul>
<li>Project the size of your mobile market</li>
<li>Define and reach your target audience</li>
<li>Set and realize your mobile vision</li>
<li>Ensure customer value through mobile execution</li>
<li>Integrate your mobile and enterprise strategies</li>
<li>Align mobile goals with IT capabilities.</li>
<li>Translate your ideas into technical specifications.</li>
<li>Understand and weigh your options—<strong><a title="Mobile Web App Development" href="#">mobile sites</a></strong>, <a title="Mobile Web App Development" href="#"><strong>mobile apps</strong></a>, <strong><a title="Native App Development" href="#">native apps</a></strong>, SMS and more</li>
<li>Platform-agnostic</li>
<li>Flexible services; we can develop and execute, work with third parties or simply provide strategic counsel</li>
</ul>
<div class="row"><div class="column large-6 small-12"><p></p>
<h4><strong>Enterprise Level Solutions</strong></h4>
<p>When <strong><a title="GE Intelligent Platforms" href="#">GE</a></strong> approached us with questions about the best mobile operating system to sit on top of their existing hardware and software, we advised them that recent kernel level changes to Android’s OS made it the best choice for them. We understand your <a title="Mobile Enterprise" href="#"><strong>enterprise</strong></a> has its own unique blend of web-based and IT architecture. We also know how to work within those systems to incorporate the right mobile platforms for you.</p>
<p></p></div><div class="column large-6 small-12"><p></p>
<h4><strong>Consumer Facing Solutions</strong></h4>
<p>When the <strong><a title="Barclays Center" href="#">Barclays Center</a></strong>, home of the <strong><a title="The Brooklyn Nets" href="#">Brooklyn Nets</a></strong>, asked us how to create a branded mobile experience for sports and music fans,&nbsp;our team suggested <a title="Cloud | API Integration" href="#"><strong>API integration</strong></a> for quick mobile internet connection, advanced streaming functionality, and in-app GPS-enabled location services. We understand your audience demands a compelling mobile experience, and create mobile strategy solutions that drive outstanding user experiences for you and your customers.</p>
<p></p></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


</article>


    </section> <!-- /#main -->


            <div id="single-nav" class="navigation sticky-fixed">
    <ul class="page-nav">
        <li class="close-panel"><a title="Back to Services" href="services.html"></a></li>
                <li class="prev-item"><a href="#" rel="prev">Mobile Design</a></li> </ul>
</div>


                                    <footer class="call-to-action">

                                <a href="#">Contact us to discuss your mobile strategy today. <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>

                            </footer>

</div>      



<footer id="footer">
    <div class="row" style="margin-right:388px; margin-left:388px;">
        <section id="text-4" class="widget widget_text"><h4 class="widget-title">Contact Us</h4>            <div class="textwidget"><address>2907 State Road 590 Suite#19<br>
Clearwater, FL 33659</address>
<p>(888) 604-0030</p>
</div>
        </section>
        <section id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
            <h4 class="widget-title">Inside HarborDev</h4>
                <div class="menu-inside-harbordev-container">
                    <ul id="menu-inside-harbordev" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-4302" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4302"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-4303" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4303"><a title="HarborDev Blog" href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-6753" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6753"><a href="#">Technology Partners</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-7827" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7827"><a href="#">Press Materials</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>

<section id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <h4 class="widget-title">Follow Us</h4>
        <div class="menu-social-media-container">
            <ul id="menu-social-media" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4305" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4305"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/harbordev">Twitter</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-4306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4306"><a target="_blank" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-4307" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4307"><a target="_blank" href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-4308" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4308"><a target="_blank" href="#">Google+</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>

<section id="text-6" class="widget widget_text">
    <h4 class="widget-title">Careers</h4>           
        <div class="textwidget"><p>Join our team and learn how we grew to become one of the top mobile app development companies worldwide.</p>
<p><a href="#">View all open positions</a></p>
</div>
        </section>  
        </div>

</footer>


    <div class="footer-bar-section">
        <p class="copyright">© 2014 HarborDev, LLC. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bar-section">
        <ul id="menu-footer-menu" class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
                <span id="obf"><a href="mailto:support@harbordev.com?subject=Support request via harbordev.com">Support</a>
<noscript>&lt;span style="unicode-bidi:bidi-override;direction:rtl;"&gt;moc.sppaeertwolliw@troppus&lt;/span&gt;</noscript></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

I would love to upload a screenshot of the problem, but I don't know how. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please recreate it using http://jsfiddle.net and put the link in your question (by editing it)... there is absolutely NO way anybody is going to read through all that code

Comment: Having briefly skimmed the code you provided, I would suspect that some definite dimensions are getting set, whether it be in the css or through images and there is not enough room on the screen for both the defined main div and the nav bar.

Comment: Nick, yes, that's what I thought too. But I can't find the issue. I took the files from the previous designer and it's a huge mess.

Comment: Try uploading it on [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post the links here or just paste the url and somebody will edit it into image

Comment: http://imgur.com/VAzwImy,y2CeQwt

Comment: see how the main div overlays the nav bar? Somehow it ignores its existence. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Is this how your layout should look? [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPSeA/1/)

```
#main-content {
color: #000;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments so far. Is there any way I can upload screenshots? That would show the problem much better.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added

```
#main {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
.main {
top: -72px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 1024px;
margin-bottom: -72px;
font-size: 1.333em;
line-height: 1.85;
} 
#post-4471 {
    margin-top: 90px;
}
```

to my CSS and all of a sudden it fixed everything. I'm not entirely sure as to why but, it did it. Thanks for everyone who participated.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, as you used "navbar-fixed-top" class for the navbar.
It applies a CSS fixed positioning.

Now you have two choices.

1. Remove "navbar-fixed-top", but in this case your navigation will become
   scrollable.
2. Add a top-padding, equal to the height of the navigation, to the top
   of body tag.

For more, read [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) Documentation.